# "Unable to instantiate activity"/"ClassNotFound exception" after upgrading Eclipse Android plugin

Tags: android

I recently got a new computer, so I've been trying to move over all my development stuff. I installed Eclipse and then the Android plugin. It told me I needed to upgrade my SDK. Okay, I did so.

However, once I moved all my code over, correctly imported etc, I now get the following crash in my LogCat when I try to run the app:

```
09-10 10:27:42.260: E/AndroidRuntime(17444): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
09-10 10:27:42.260: E/AndroidRuntime(17444): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.bearwaves.uplift/com.bearwaves.uplift.MainActivity}: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.bearwaves.uplift.MainActivity
09-10 10:27:42.260: E/AndroidRuntime(17444):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1993)
09-10 10:27:42.260: E/AndroidRuntime(17444):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2104)
09-10 10:27:42.260: E/AndroidRuntime(17444):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:132)
09-10 10:27:42.260: E/AndroidRuntime(17444):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1157)
09-10 10:27:42.260: E/AndroidRuntime(17444):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
09-10 10:27:42.260: E/AndroidRuntime(17444):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
09-10 10:27:42.260: E/AndroidRuntime(17444):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4575)
09-10 10:27:42.260: E/AndroidRuntime(17444):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
09-10 10:27:42.260: E/AndroidRuntime(17444):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
09-10 10:27:42.260: E/AndroidRuntime(17444):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:789)
09-10 10:27:42.260: E/AndroidRuntime(17444):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:556)
09-10 10:27:42.260: E/AndroidRuntime(17444):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
09-10 10:27:42.260: E/AndroidRuntime(17444): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.bearwaves.uplift.MainActivity
09-10 10:27:42.260: E/AndroidRuntime(17444):    at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:61)
09-10 10:27:42.260: E/AndroidRuntime(17444):    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:501)
09-10 10:27:42.260: E/AndroidRuntime(17444):    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:461)
09-10 10:27:42.260: E/AndroidRuntime(17444):    at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1023)
09-10 10:27:42.260: E/AndroidRuntime(17444):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1984)
09-10 10:27:42.260: E/AndroidRuntime(17444):    ... 11 more
```

This is odd because my code hasn't changed at all. I tried moving everything over to a new project - twice - same result. The manifest works for my code when using the default 'Hello World' activity but not for the new code - I also suspect it's not a problem related to SD card because this occurs on the emulator also.

I'm confused as to what could have changed to the point where my code no longer functions.

Comment: Was your old SDK version 16 or less?

Comment: did you choose **project from existing code** or **new project** ??

Comment: Are you using any external library file?

Comment: @NickT: Yes, I believe it was 15.

Comment: @SpK: Yes, they're in a folder called 'lib'.

Comment: that's why it is happening .. just go to File > New > Project
and choose **Android project from existing code**
try it

Comment: The two answers referring to the 'libs' folder are correct. This came in at r17 hence my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you had any external libraries in your Java build path, you must include them in a libs folder.

Comment: They're in a folder called 'lib', they're .jar files - is 'libs' the new standard?

Comment: @JoelAuterson yea they added it during that time.